Is there any Way to create a discount plugin for users who are registered on another webapp?
I am new to Moodle and I have created a basic course page where a user can buy that course after clicking enrol button.
First I want to create a plugin or filter which is easier which will check for his membership also i have created API for this, I am stuck on integrating with Moodle ,
Then it will show the discounted price or original price base above condition and then after clicking on enrol button it should show the prices on stripe according,
any help will be appreciated
I have tried to create plugin using chatgpt but its not working.

Have a look at enrol plugins that use payment gateways - eg: https://moodle.org/plugins/enrol_gwpayments

Thanks @RussellEngland does this plugin allows us to add another webapp api ? to check for users who are members there ?
I just want to dynamically give discount to students who are members there is this possible to achieve ?
